# Link to archive.php - WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm just wondering if there is a way to link a button to an `archive.php` for a specific author in WordPress.

The thing is that I am using author.php to display some information about the author, but I would like to be able to link to the archive.php from `author.php` and use the `archive.php` to show the author's posts on a separate page.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: Have you tried anything by yourself?

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
<?php the_author_posts_link(); ?>
```

You can read more about it here in the codex: [wordpress codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_author_posts_link)